# Ascending order and Descending Java

Tags: java, for-loop, do-while, logical-operators

Hi here's my problem i cant seem to print my outputs correctly i guess i'm having a logical error in my code, it doesn't print when i put an ascending number then a descending. i'm kind of new to programming too.
 Code:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    public class tester {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int n, i, k, j;
            int asc = 0, 
            Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);

            do {

                System.out.print("How many numbers to process : ");
                k = x.nextInt(); 

                if(k<=1) {
                    System.out.println("Enter a number greater than 1");
                }
            } while(k<=1);

            System.out.printf("Please enter %d numbers: ",k);
            n = x.nextInt();  

            for(i=0; i<n-1; i++) { 
                j = x.nextInt();
                if( j < n) { 
                    asc++;              // is this right?
                } else {
                    asc--;
                }
            }
            if (asc==k) {
                System.out.print("Not Growing Up."); 
            } 
            if (asc!=k) { 
                System.out.print("Growing Up.");
            }
        }   
   }
```

Here are the outputs

```
 Example outputs (what i'm trying to get)
 How many numbers to process : 4
 Please enter 4 numbers : 1 2 3 4
 Growing up.

 How many numbers to process : 4
 Please enter 4 numbers : 4 3 2 1
 Not Growing up.
```

This is my problem :

```
 How many numbers to process : 4
 Please enter 4 numbers : 1 2 1 3
 Growing up.         // it should be not growing up.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to iterate through all numbers. You can just check if the previous number is lower (if growing). If not, print and return. Check my example code.

Replace

```
n = x.nextInt(); 
for (i=0; i<n-1; i++) { 
    j = x.nextInt();
    if( j < n) { 
        asc++;              // is this right?
    } else {
        asc--;
    }
}
if (asc==k) {
    System.out.print("Not Growing Up."); 
} 
if (asc!=k) { 
    System.out.print("Growing Up.");
}
```

With

```
int prev = x.nextInt();
for (i=0; i<k-1; i++) { 
    j = x.nextInt();
    if (j < prev) { System.out.print("Not Growing Up."); return; }
    prev = j;
}
System.out.print("Growing Up.");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String numbers = "1 2 3 4";  // Let's take this input for example
    int temp = 0;               // This use to compare previous integer
    boolean isAsc = false;     // This store whether the digits is growing up or not

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(numbers); // Declare StringTokenizer
     while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {

       int next = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());  // Put the first integer in next (1)

       if(next > temp){    // if (1) > 0

         temp = next;     // Assign 1 to temp, next time digit 2 will compare with digit 1         
         isAsc = true;   // Assign the ascending to true

       } else

         isAsc = false;
     }

    if(isAsc)
      System.out.print("Growing up.");
    else
      System.out.print("Not growing up.");
  }
```

Your can store the user input as a string like the variable `numbers` I've declared and break them into each token for compare purpose.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.*;

public class A1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a[]={2,5,0,1};
    Arrays.sort(a);
    int b= a.length;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {

        System.out.println(+a[i]+"\t"+a[b-1]);
        b--;



    }


}

}
```